# Generate C# automatic properties with Codedom

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, codedom

is there a way Generate C# automatic properties with Codedom **or** maybe an other set of libreries that i can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeDom is supposed to be some sort of [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) which can be converted to multiple languages (typically C# and VB.NET). Therefore, you'll not find features which are syntactic sugar of a specific language in CodeDom.

Answer (score 8):

You can use CodeSnippetTypeMember class for that purpose.

For example:

```
    CodeTypeDeclaration newType = new CodeTypeDeclaration("TestType");
    CodeSnippetTypeMember snippet = new CodeSnippetTypeMember();
    snippet.Comments.Add(new CodeCommentStatement("this is integer property", true));
    snippet.Text="public int IntergerProperty { get; set; }";
    newType.Members.Add(snippet);
```

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not: [C# CodeDom Automatic Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583516/c-codedom-automatic-property)

Take a look into [this article](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/565-Generating-C-Class-File-Sample-cs-Dynamically-us.aspx) to get some useful examples

Comment: so are there any other libraries that i can use ?

Comment: @Yassir It's really not that hard to create a backing field and use them in getter/setter.

Comment: you dont need; as Marc Gravell said, you need to implement it yourself, as they are just a compiler trick (i.e. .net compiler creates a private variable to hold your automatic property value)

Comment: actually i'm not compiling the generated code i add it to a project so i need the generated classes to have automatic properties

Comment: In that case, you could to use a `CodeSnippetStatement` and hardcode that property

Answer (score 1):

Actually the comments about it being easy to use a CodeSnippetStatement are misleading because CodeTypeDeclaration has no statements collection that you can add those snippets to.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:  According to [How to: Create a Class Using CodeDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        // Declare the ID Property.
        CodeMemberProperty IDProperty = new CodeMemberProperty();
        IDProperty.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
        IDProperty.Name = "Id";
        IDProperty.HasGet = true;
        IDProperty.HasSet = true;
        IDProperty.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Int16));
        IDProperty.Comments.Add(new CodeCommentStatement(
        "Id is identity"));
        targetClass.Members.Add(IDProperty);
```

Comment: This does not work, as it generates two empty `set` and `get` methods which will result in compiling errors. The `CodeSnippetTypeMember` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23876973/191148) is the solution